# putting a new line in form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So when I am writing text into a form input and when I try to put a new line when I hit enter it submits a comment. How can I have it not submit my comment but instead when I hit enter I want it to add a new line ?

this is what I have

http://jsfiddle.net/rduhsp19/3/

```
<form name="formcheck" id="formcheck2" onsubmit="" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="comment" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; border: 1px solid ##dddddd; padding: 2px;" size="70">
<input type="hidden" name="part_number" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Comment" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px;">
<input type="hidden" name="comments_original_content_id" value="">
</form>
```

I've tried to do this

```
$('input').keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var s = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(s+"\n");
   }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use a TEXTAREA then?

Comment: @A.Wolff that was my last choice :)...

Comment: BTW, if you do what you say you did, the enter is cancelled successfully: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/22he9mdx/ (you didn;t include jQuery in the fiddle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding new lines by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can use HTML `<textarea>` tag.